# parsing commands into tree python : multiple key dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

I have a list of commands looking like this :

set_string equipment_type 3 Pump

All commands almost follow this template:

**cmd**_**type** **propertyname** **equipment_id** **value**

What I am trying to do is to go through a txt document full of this kind of commands and store all possible combinations of command statements. I am only interested in cmd, type, dimension of equipment_id and property name.

What I already did was using a dictionary with tuples (cmd,type,dimension) as keys and a set of property names as a value.

But I would like to add a notion of priority into this data structure : cmd then type then dimension. Is there a tree-like data structure in python that can permit me to store this kind of data? First layer would be : cmd, Second layer : type, Third layer would be : dimension and the leaves are the set of property names that can be used following the corresponding path in the tree.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can store another dictionary as a value.

Comment: Thanks for the question, my reputation just got over `0b1000000000000000` :)

Comment: I am still not sure how the point system works... all I know is that if my question gets downvoted I am blocked from asking questions for a while ^^'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use nested dicts, nested defaultdicts or a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

With standard dicts, you'd use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
tree = {}
tree.setdefault(cmd, {}).setdefault(cmd_type, {}).setdefault(dimension, []).append(prop)
```

It would give you a dict of dicts of dicts of lists.
If you want sets at the leaves, you could use:

```
tree.setdefault(cmd, {}).setdefault(cmd_type, {}).setdefault(dimension, set()).add(prop)
```

As an example:

```
data = [
  ('cmd1', 'typeA', 3, 'propertyX'),
  ('cmd1', 'typeA', 3, 'propertyZ'),
  ('cmd1', 'typeB', 2, 'propertyY'),
  ('cmd2', 'typeA', 3, 'propertyX'),
  ('cmd2', 'typeB', 1, 'propertyZ'),
  ('cmd2', 'typeA', 1, 'propertyX'),
  ('cmd1', 'typeB', 2, 'propertyZ')
] 

tree = {}
for cmd, cmd_type, dimension, prop in data:
    tree.setdefault(cmd, {}).setdefault(cmd_type, {}).setdefault(dimension, []).append(prop)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(tree)
```

It outputs:

```
{'cmd1': {'typeA': {3: ['propertyX', 'propertyZ']},
          'typeB': {2: ['propertyY', 'propertyZ']}},
 'cmd2': {'typeA': {1: ['propertyX'], 3: ['propertyX']},
          'typeB': {1: ['propertyZ']}}}
```

With defaultdicts, your code would look like:

```
tree = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)))
for cmd, cmd_type, dimension, prop in data:
    tree[cmd][cmd_type][dimension].append(prop)
```

Comment: This should work. But I need to have sets at the end because same combinations may repeat. In the last setdefault I can use set() instead of [ ]?

Answer (score 2):

One relatively clean way is the infinetely nested `defaultdict` tree:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)

t = tree()
for cmd, type, dim, prop in (l.split() for l in open('file.txt')):
    t[cmd][type][dim][prop] = True
```

This will allow you to iterate through all props of one `(cmd, type, dim)` triplet via:

```
for prop in t[cmd][type][dim]:
    # ...
```

Comment: That's a fun structure! You could add depth parameter to your tree in order to have another type (e.g. `set` or `list` at the leaves).

Comment: @EricDuminil Yeah, it is definitely extendable, but I didn't want to clutter it to keep the main principle as clearly visible as possible (without passing down params etc.). Your answer had the OP covered already, but I felt this should be mentioned :) And with the `bool` at the end, you mimick a set at the previous level, after all.